# I have an issue with configuring openvpn server and running it

Tags: openvpn, public-key, rsa

### *****Server Log*****

`Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in server.ovpn:4: cert (2.4.9) Use --help for more information.`

### *****server configuration*****

```
server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
ca ca.crt
cert serverport 1194
proto udp
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

```
dev tun
server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
ca ca.crt
cert serverVPN.crt
key serverVPN.key
dh dh1024.pem
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
client-to-client
log-append /var/log/openvpn
group daemon
daemon
verb 3.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
client-to-client
log-append /var/log/openvpn
group daemon
daemon
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly on the line specified in the error message.

```
cert serverport 1194
```

You are meant to provide the filename of the certificate with the `cert` directive, and the `serverport` directive should be on the next line.

Comment: I type "cert serverport 1194" instead of "port 1194" i got my mistake and repeating the command "server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
ca ca.crt" on the first line

Comment: thank you sir  for pointing my mistake

Answer (score 0):

the correct server configuration is:

port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
ca ca.crt
cert serverVPN.crt
key serverVPN.key
dh dh1024.pem
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
client-to-client
log-append /var/log/openvpn
group daemon
daemon
verb 3.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
client-to-client
log-append /var/log/openvpn
group daemon
daemon
verb 3